# spring boot jdbc The server time zone value 'Jerusalem Standard Time' is unrecognized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

this is the first time i use jdbc in spring boot so i was following this guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

everything was looking fine till i tried to compile it and got this error:

```
The server time zone value 'Jerusalem Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan Johx im using mysql workbench 8.0

Comment: I added a solution that I hope that solves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to add ?serverTimezone=IST in your application.properties on line spring.datasource.url = ...

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?serverTimezone=IST

Comment: the second option fixed it, thanks! how did you know its IST? i tried to search timezones and timezones formats and didn't really manage to find anything usefull. ill accept your answer as soon as i finish my testing to be sure its fixed.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/israel/jerusalem here Jerusalem is part of Israel

Comment: Also note that IST is an ambiguous timezone code, as it is used for Israel Standard Time, Irish Standard Time and India Standard Time.